# Directory needs to be writable

Tags: php, centos, chmod, phpfox

am installing PHPFOX on Centos 7 with Apache2 and getting Directory needs to be writable for PF.Base and PF.Site 
and i did chmod 777 for both and tried for main folder and same issue ,

below snapshots

Any recommendations ?

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/41b94f83a3993d33b2bd06993be07f66.png

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/71028b8a60497ec8c9948ab488c3f90f.png

Comment: Have you checked the ownership and group for files and folders?

Comment: Are you sure you made it writeable for the web-user, not just whatever user you were logged in with? Normally the web-user is something like www-data, or similar.

Comment: Files Owner = 0 and Group = 0

Comment: This question really hasn't been asked properly.  Refer to: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And make the effort to complete the 2-minute site tour as well.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/8449910ddd495cd44be6aac53b2a5abc.png

Answer (score 1):

For some webservers, even if they have full permissions (777), they will refuse to work with the directory because *other* users/groups have full permissions to the directory.

The better approach:

- change ownership of the directory to whatever user the webserver operates as. For PHP, this can be determined by serving a file with contents `<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>`
- run a `chmod 755` command to make the directory writable only by the owner. 
  Note that for files, the permission should be 644.
- run a `chown` to transfer ownership to the webserver

For more information, you can see this [canonical answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver) on serverfault.com

Comment: whoami = root
and for chown i tried chown root:root /var/www/html/ 
and same issue

Comment: Your whoami should not be run in your terminal, but in a php script. `<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>` I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: i did whoami on php and the user was apache then i made chown for /var/www/html and for the folders i need to be 777

Comment: Folders need to be 755 owned by apache.

Comment: this is the file permissions now and owner id 
https://i.gyazo.com/8449910ddd495cd44be6aac53b2a5abc.png

Comment: Is that group ID valid? Group ID may or may not be same as user ID

Comment: both for apache group and user

Answer (score 0):

CD to root path of phpFox site. Then try this command line:

```
chmod 777 PF.Base PF.Site
```

Refresh your installation page. If it still doesn't work, please attach a screenshot here, so I can check more detail.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/ad58549a48c4780a8d7917abb839ce5c.png

https://i.gyazo.com/1f13cd8f92d56bd8c6cddda7bfea0491.png

Comment: It seems the permission is not correct. It should be **drwxrwxrwx**, not *drwsrwsrwx*.